# Modus ponens and left-nested conditionals (part 2)

Tags: logic

Someone told me that **(a ⊃ b) ⊃* a* and *((a ⊃ b) ⊃ a) ⊃ a* together with modus ponens entail *a* and subsequently *b*. Is this true? And if yes, could please someone show me how to prove it? (I haven't found the proof yet).

Comment: The inplications together with modus ponens clearly entail $a$. They do not entail $b$, as you can verify by means of a truth table.

Comment: So you disagree with hamam_Abdallah below?

Comment: No. He’s just proving that they entail $a$.

Comment: So why the entry about Curry's paradox in wikipedia says that they also entail b? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%27s_paradox (formal proof section): "An alternative proof is via Peirce's law. If X = X → Y then (X → Y) → X. This together with Peirce's law ((X → Y) → X) → X and modus ponens implies X and subsequently Y (as in above proof)."

Comment: Because in that argument $X$ is the implication $X\to Y$, so that once you have $X$, you have $X\land(X\to Y)$ and therefore $Y$. But that argument depends crucially on the fact that $X$ is the same as $X\to Y$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Modus Ponens argument insure that
$$(p\implies q) \wedge p \therefore q$$

Now, take
$$p=(a\implies b)\implies a$$
and
$$q=a$$